# Different width on the textarea for custom reject reason

Tags: bug, design, user-interface, layout

For a while now, under the following conditions:

- Ubuntu 12.04 LTS (precise)
- Firefox 14.0.1 or Google Chrome 21.0.1180.89
- Landscape monitor with 1920x1080 pixels

The `<textarea class="actual-edit-overlay"></textarea>` under **Why are you rejecting this edit?** appears larger (with a width of `657px`) and breaking the layout:

[image: textarea format wrong]

While on the remaining browsers and on every browser under Windows 7 the width appears with a width of `579px`:

[image: textarea format ok]

Is this and issue that anyone else can confirm, or am I out of luck and need to wait for a browser upgrade?

**Note:** All other SE sites that I use present the `textarea` with the correct format and width.